# Retina display device width is not autofit in on ipad when using device width

Tags: html, css, retina-display, retina, pixel-ratio

Currently I am working for a website where I used Retina Ready Coding. The retina display (new iPad) has a resolution of 2048 x 1536 pixels while the general iPad/Tab has resolution of 1024x768 pixels. As per Retina’s law, Whenever I used body width / container width 1536px in

```css
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { body{ width: 1536px !important; }, .container{ width: 1536px !important; } }.
```

This should autofit the width:1536px into 768px(as its pixel-ratio-2). But It showing zoomin the full site into iPad. Whenever I touched into the iPad it goes to fit into 768px from 1536px in width.
Do anyone have any solution for this? I am facing same problem for Retina display Mobile device.

Comment: @ Adrian, Already I have used this viewport.<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved !!!

I have to used this meta TAG

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1" />
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Have you set a viewport using meta tags? this behaviour looks like there is no viewport meta tag. Try changing/adding the viewport settings with this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

or this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
```

or both:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

also check [this link for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) explanations

Comment: how do you even know if OP is using meta tag? don't assume things when answering

Comment: @ Adrian,

ALready I have used this viewport.
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">